# Searching values from dataframe1 to dataframe2 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

let's say I have a my source dataframe:

```
A B C
a 1 string1
b 1 string1
b 4 string2
c 2 string4
d 2 string2
```

and I have my input dataframe

```
A B C
a null string1
b null string2
```

How am I able to cross check values from my input dataframe to my source I want to find which rows in my **source dataframe** that has values from my **input dataframe**. I tried isin but its returning a dataframe full of **nan** values

Result would be a df:

```
A B C
a 1 string1 #Ref to a null string1
b 1 string1 #Ref to b null string2
b 4 string2 #Ref to b null string2
d 2 string2 #Ref to b null string2
```

Comment: What values are you checking from both? I don't quite understand how you got your resulting df.

Comment: It seems that you are searching column 'C'

Comment: @vikrantrana im searching for all columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are filtering your source df keeping only rows that have values in column C that are in your input df column C. If that is the case, you can use `input_df['C'].unique()` to give you an array of the unique values in column C in your input df, and you can use `isin` to filter your source df:

```
source_df[source_df['C'].isin(input_df['C'].unique())]
```

which gives an output of:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   1   string1
1   b   1   string1
2   b   4   string2
4   d   2   string2
```

Comment: how do we do this for all columns?

Comment: You could merge on the columns you wish to match. One of the suggested links goes into depth on merging.